# Embedding video in Facebook without YouTube

Tags: facebook, youtube, video, facebook-integration, video-streaming

If I post a link to a YouTube video on Facebook it will embed the video on the page.

What are some other sites besides YouTube that will also embed video if I post a link on Facebook?

I don't want to upload directly to Facebook because the number of views isn't counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head : [Dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com), [Vimeo](http://www.vimeo.com)